# iOS Storyboard: how do you edit a content view larger than screen in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a view that is larger than screen, I need to put it in a UIScrollView.

So I first add an UIViewController to story board, then, I add a UIScrollView to the root view of my view controller, then when I add subviews of UIScrollView, but I can't add them outside the scrollview area I can see, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Select Freeform in Simulated Metrics for the UIViewController question to make it bigger.  Then you can resize your scroll view to show all the sub views. When finished, you can resize the scroll view to the required size.

Answer (score 15):

Change the simulated size of the view controller to Freeform and then you can set the size to whatever you want. After editing, you may want to set it back.

[image: freeform]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1:**

1) put your subview into scrollview's visible area

2) change frame of the new subview as you wish

[image: change frame]

3) change **contentSize** property of scrollview with runtime attributes

[image: runtime attributes]

**Edit 2:**
u can create a new view with xib, which contains all your subviews, and then add this view on scrollview OR u can use storyboard's *Container View* like this:

[image]

p.s.: don't forget about **contentSize** (point 3 in my first edit), but if you are using auto-layout, you need to set it programmatically like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 250);
}
```

Comment: My question is how to edit it in Interface Builder, not how to use code to achieve it.

Comment: By this way I can't see content cropped by the scroll view in Interface Builder, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. put a scroll view in the view controller ,and put a view inside the scroll view named containerView.
2. design the big content in another view controller (named bigContentView)
3. in code ,view load event ,

a. get the bigContentView by storyboard Id. ( get the controller and use controller.view)

b. create the outlet to the containerView.

c. update the containerView's frame according your requirement.(update the width and height)

d. bigContentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

e. containerView addSubView:bigContentView.