# How to change a view height with attribute insbector?

Tags: ios, view, xib, nib

In my view I want to add 15 buttons, but the screen height isn't sufficient.

So I decided to use `UIScrollView`, but the problem is that I can't add them to the view in the xib file, because the view (at xib) has a limited length. What should I do?

Comment: check my recent reply here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682729/ios-storyboard-how-do-you-edit-a-content-view-larger-than-screen-in-a-uiscrollv